# How to turn on Direct3D acceleration

Tags: technical-issues, directx-9, the-settlers

Hi I was trying to play the settlers 6 which as I know uses DirectX 9. During startup it said `Graphics Engine could not be initialized` so I started dxdiag where one point was deactivated: Direct3D acceleration.

One could argue that my graphics card is to old but I am sure that this game was running perfectly last time and the 64-bit version of dxdiag states that the hardware acceleration is on!

So I want to know how to turn it on because reinstalling DirectX 9 always stated that it was already installed.

(Before someone asks my graphics card is nVidia GeForce 260 GTX)

I recently tested it with windows 8 and it worked without problems.

Comment: So is this resolved for you?  What OS were you using when it wasn't working?

Comment: I used windows 7 with the (at that time) latest driver actually the same as the windows 8